# Laravel 4 Blade BUG

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Having trouble getting blade template to work... all that is displayed on the page is:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
```

Here is the route:

```
Route::get('login', function(){ 
    return View::make('admin.login');
});
```

Here is the template: layouts/admin.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="large-12 columns">
  <div id="wrap" class="large-8 large-centered columns"> 
    @yield('content') 
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the view: views/admin/login.blade.php (no breaks or space before @extends)

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')
<h1>Admin Login</h1>
...
@stop
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to name the file `xxxx.blade.php`.

Comment: No... all the files have .blade.php

Comment: Try to return just layouts.admin from route. What is the output?

Comment: Does your controller set a layout?

Comment: I'm not using a controller... just a route.

Comment: Everything looks fine so far.

Comment: Do you have a space at the top of the login.blade.php file or is it exactly as it is presented here?

Comment: I've tried your code and it worked as it suppose to do. What error you get ? Check again that, all your `view` files have `filename.blade.php` name format.

Comment: any of these space or EOL, CR, LF, Enter, \n at the start of the template file will cause a problem

Comment: If I remove `blade` from `login.blade.php` then I can see `@extends('layouts.admin') @section('content')
Admin Login

@stop` in the browser.

Comment: No spaces and all files have .blade.php and the frustrating part is that there is no error.

Comment: Check the log in `app\storage\logs` and see if there is anything in there that looks like it would be relevant.

Comment: No errors in the logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wasted hours of my life. There was nothing in the code that was wrong and I would still possibly consider this a bug since no errors were generated. I finally ended up creating NEW files with the EXACT same code and replacing the existing blade files and suddenly it magically works. I'm not sure if somehow the files were corrupted or what but hopefully this will save somebody hours of frustration.

Comment: Probably line endings, they can mess with your head.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any errors in your code, it works fine for me and more people here. So you might have problems in some other part of your code that you're not showing to us.

I just made [this git repository](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/laravel-test) reproducing the code you posted here.

It may prove to you that Laravel works and sometimes the problem is just elsewhere. Or it may prove to us that in some environments Laravel is broken, wich might help the project.

So, please, give it a try and tell us what you get going to the route `http://your-host/login`.

Comment: Did you used the one I created?

Comment: This isn't my package. Somehow you are missing Laravel's classes from the vendor/laravel folder. Do a `composer update` and a `artisan dump-autoload`.

Comment: The problem you have is in some code we are not seeing. You will have to post more code here so we can help you. Or, if your project is not big, you can copy the relevant parts of it to my repository and use it as a base. This repository is just a blank Laravel repository where I added the layout, the view and a route to login, nothing else.

Answer (score -2):

I've had the same exact problem.  You are using UTF.  UTF leaves a byte order mark or BOM at the beginning of the file and it's invisible to most text editors.  Just download a [BOM REMOVING SOFTWARE](http://www.bryntyounce.com/filebomdetector.htm) so that it will work.

cheers.